# Testing Daylight Savings Time Switch

Tags: windows, ntp, time, testing, daylight-saving

We have a case where we need to test some scripting and application code related to daylight savings time.  We wanted to simulate the daylight savings time switch by disabling the NTP service and changing the system time into the future. Obviously infrastructure components may not play nice with the system with a skewed time like kerberos authentication.

Does anyone know how we can validate and test the daylight savings time switch (we are focused on Windows systems), or is the only option to create a separate environment with our infrastructure components?